# Storing outputs from convolutional layers

Tags: tensorflow, cnn

I am working on a CNN architecture over video clips that attempts to separate temporal and spatial features, inspired by [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6720945/). The relevant architecture is on Figure 5(b).

Here is my idea: I want to take each frame and feed it through two 2D convolutional layers. After I feed each frame through these layers, I want to take all the frames and feed them into a 3D convolutional layer as one input, so that I can extract temporal features. However, I don't know how to save each output of the two 2D convolutional layers in Tensorflow. Any advice would be helpful.